# IPC with pipes inbetween packaged UWP app and Desktop .Net 6.0 program

Tags: c#, uwp, pipe, ipc, sid

A couple questions about the intricacies of doing pipe IPC in UWP (Don't tell me to use an app service, it's too low latency of a solution for my project).

I'm trying to get working IPC between two of my projects, one of them being a UWP packaged app, and the other being a C# .net6 app. I have successfully created a [NamedPipeServerStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream?view=net-6.0) inside of my .net6 program. Initially, my UWP side pipe client (NamedPipeClientStream) would fail during creation due to a "Access to the path is denied" error.

[Doing research](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/sharing-named-objects), I have deduced that I need to add some access rules related to my UWP package's SID so that my UWP app can successfully communicate with my external app. It seems vanilla .net NamedPipeServerStream does not allow for access rules to be added via constructor, but I was able to work around it with [a nuget package,  NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion/). I was able to get a SID using a function described in the docs, although this turned out to be the wrong SID. Using a hard coded SID from the powershell command "CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s", I was able to successfully create the NamedPipeClientStream object in my UWP app, getting past the access denied error.

However, the connect method that I call directly after does not succeed. I end up getting an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Principal.Windows,
> Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
> The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
> reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

A couple questions:

1. Is making a pipe between the two projects actually this difficult? Am I close to the light at the end of the tunnel?
2. Why did my two methods of receiving the SID for my packaged app result in different SIDS? Is there a nice programmatic way in C# to do this?

Here are some of my code samples:

Server:

```
//IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
//var result = DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName("PackageFamilyName", ref ptr);
//var appSid = new SecurityIdentifier(ptr); //results in incorrect SID
var appSid = new SecurityIdentifier("hardCodedSID");
var access = new PipeSecurity();
SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
access.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(sid, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
access.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(sid, PipeAccessRights.AccessSystemSecurity, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
access.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(appSid, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
access.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(appSid, PipeAccessRights.AccessSystemSecurity, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
pipeServer = NamedPipeServerStreamConstructors.New("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.None, 0, 0, access);
pipeServer.WaitForConnection(); // gets past here when client creates NamedPipeClientStream
```

Client:

```
pipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
pipeClient.Connect(5000); // fails here
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get somewhat of a working solution doing independent research. A couple answers:

1. NamedPipeServerStreamConstructors.New via [NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NamedPipeServerStream.NetFrameworkVersion/) is a deprecated strategy. .Net 6.0 provides what I was trying to do via [NamedPipeServerStreamACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstreamacl?view=net-6.0). I opted to use this instead of what is currently in my sample.
2. I could not figure out the error with "System.Security.Principal.Windows" that was happening in my UWP app when trying to connect using NamedPipeClientStream. I think it just might be a bug or something. If anyone knows what is going on there, would be appreciated.
3. To work around #2, I implemented a lower level version of what I was trying to do using [CreateFileW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew). This is a lower level c++ function, whilst the previous is the C# equivalent. It appears that the C# version has some intelligence with the ".\pipe\" prefix, so it is not needed when creating the pipe server. However, the C++ function in the client code for UWP will need to include that (no use of LOCAL prefix was needed). With this set up, I was able to send requests from my .Net 6.0 pipe server to my UWP pipe client and get responses back. Towards the end are some code snippets:
4. Still do not know the answer as to why I got the incorrect SID via [DeriveAppContainerSidFromAppContainerName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstreamacl?view=net-6.0). I looked in my Registry and could not even located the SID it was trying to point me at. Mega confused.

Client code:

```
var fileName = @"\\.\pipe\\testpipe";
 IntPtr pipeHandle = CreateFileW(fileName,
  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
  FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
  IntPtr.Zero,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
  IntPtr.Zero);
 if (pipeHandle.ToInt32() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
  var err = $"Failed to create pipe client, win32 error: {Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()}";
  throw new Exception(err);
 }
 stream = new FileStream(new SafeFileHandle(pipeHandle, true), FileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Server construction code:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous, 512, 512, access);
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please share the details about Client Code. I'm facing the same problem like you. Need to communicate UWP to Console App. Could you please share your sample app